# Undefined index in php when getting value passed from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the value that I passed in AJAX to PHP. It shows an alert that says, "Success!" however it when I try to display the value in PHP, it says undefined index. Also I am passing it in the same page.

Whenever I click a button, it opens a modal and I also passing values from that button to the modal. This is evident in my JS code.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

            var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); //im trying to pass this value to php, e.g. 5
            var time = $(e.relatedTarget).data('time');
            var name = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name');
            var stat = $(e.relatedTarget).data('stat');
            var desc = $(e.relatedTarget).data('desc');
            alert(id);
            $("#task_id_edit").val(id);
            $("#new-taskID").val(id);

            $("#allotted_time_edit").val(time);
            $("#task_name_edit").val(name);
            $("#task_status_edit").val(stat);
            $("#task_desc_edit").val(desc);
            $("#task_id_ref2").val(id);


           //AJAX CODE HERE
           $(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'tasks.php?id='<?php $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ""; echo $id; ?>,
                    data: { "userID" : id },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("success!"); //this display
                    }
                });
           });



           }); // line 1131
        });
</script>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

   $uid = $_POST['userID'];
   echo $uid." is the value"; 

?>
```

It keeps getting an error that says, undefined index: userID. I am confused. Please help me how to fix this. Your help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: do you get any errors on javascript console ?

Comment: well it says, "tasks.php:1131 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" .. i have edited the question to show what line 1131 is

Comment: don't quote userID in data. not saying its the problem but

Answer (score 2):

Echo the number in the javascript string.

Currently you will get:

> url:'tasks.php?id='1,

The `1` should be concatenated or inside the quote. Try:

```
url: 'tasks.php?id=<?php $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ""; echo $id; ?>',
```

or take that parameter out since it doesn't appear to be being used.

Comment: isent the op geting the value via post?

Comment: The AJAX is sending a `POST` but the `url` is a `GET`, incorrectly formatted.

Comment: but are they the same id's? i suspect they are 2 diffirent ones

Comment: I'm not sure what the usage of `id` is, but the JS concatenation is incorrect.

Comment: yes, i agree :-) but post should still work regardless.

Comment: Yea, their error is a JS error, not PHP as I read it. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`... or are these different issues?

Answer (score -2):

Just put the `$_POST['userID']` in a if statement

Undefined index: UserID is not a error it is a warning

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['userID'])
   {
   $uid = $_POST['userID'];
   echo $uid." is the value"; 
   }
   else
   {
     echo "Sorry Value cant be printed";
   }

?>
```

Comment: thank you but the one in the else statement prints :(

Comment: if you directly open the php page you will always fall into the else part, because the POST variables are not set.